# data extraction from textfile in python 3

Tags: python

I have faced a difficultly in extracting the last data into my program through a text file.I am very new to Python and please pardon me if the answer is really simple one.

I have this sequence of data set in a text file and i have already extracted USD as my selling currency GBP as my buying currency and 0.50443 as my exchange rate.But i don't know how to extract cost as my Transaction cost and 0.0001 as the relevant value for that variable.

`{"USD_GBP_COST": "0.50443,0.0001", "USD_USD_COST": "1.00000,0.0000", "USD_EUR_COST": "0.73951,0.01211"}`

following is my code for other parts:

```
currency_rates = json.loads(page)

 splited_rates = re.compile("([A-Z]{3})_([A-Z]{3})")#split the string which is read from the url,it should be any 3 uppercase characters sperated by a _ 

for key in currency_rates:
    matches=splited_rates.match(key)
    log_con_rate = -math.log(float(currency_rates[key]))
    selling_currency = matches.group(1).encode('ascii','ignore')
    buying_currency = matches.group(2).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: What happens if when you run this? What's not working here? What output did you want?

Comment: Hey ,It gives me this error                                                                                             File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 407 (char 406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
float(currency_rates[key])
```

which gives the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.50443,0.0001'`. I think that message is pretty self-explanatory. It is telling you that you need to pick the string apart into two numbers before trying to turn them into `float`s:

```
con_rate_s, transaction_cost_s = currency_rates[key].split(",")
log_con_rate = -math.log(float(con_rate_s))
transaction_cost = float(transaction_cost_s)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the respond,i tried that but i am getting an error like this                                                                                                                                          File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 407 (char 406)

Comment: Well, that is a completely different error. Your question says "How do I get transaction cost out of this dictionary?" But the problem you report now is that `json.loads()` does not like your json file. Look inside the file and see if you can make out what the problem is. Count the characters up to 406 if you have to. The message is very explicit: it is looking for `:` at that point and not finding it.

Comment: yes it was an error in my data file.now figured it out .stupid me to not to see that.Now it works.Thank you so much :)